# Can't pass application test for uiviewcontroller and it's UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, testing, uiviewcontroller

I want to check(test) if a **UITextField** inside a **UIViewController** *became first responder* or not.

Here is my code of UIViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [myUITextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

And Here is my test code:

```
- (void) testThatMyUITextFieldShouldBeFirstResponder {
    MyViewController * ViewController =
    [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (MyViewController) {
        [MyViewController loadView];

        STAssertTrue(MyViewController.myUITextField.isFirstResponder, @"myUITextField is not first responder");
    }
}
```

Although the line [myUITextField becomeFirstResponder] has been executed correctly but the isFirstResponder property is not true.

What is the problem and How can I solve it?

Comment: I am sure that view did load function is called, But I can't understand why myUITextField.isFirstResponder property is not set to YES!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set it as first responder in viewDidLoad, when de VC didn't finish to layout the subviews. Do it @ viewDidLayoutSubviews, viewWillApear or viewDidapear. Then, @ your test function add [MyViewController.view setNeedsLayout];

Answer (score 0):

Replace This mathed this will work fine,When u create your textfield give them tag 5

```
-(void) testThatMyUITextFieldShouldBeFirstResponder
{
// get your textfield
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        UITextField *textField=(UITextField *)view;
        // and get if yoyr textfield tag is 5
        if ((textField.tag==5) &&[textField isFirstResponder])
        {
            NSLog(@"Your TextField is Firstrsponder");
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: It didn't help at all!
I know my textfield

Comment: if there are more than one text field give tag.

Comment: Yes there is more than one!

Comment: And as I said I have the access to that.

Comment: Here i change my answer and in your code give that text Field  tag 5

Comment: I think you didn't realize what problem is!
Problem is not selecting the textField.
problem is why I call becomeFirstResponder in viewDidLoad and the isFirstResponder property doesn't set correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Put assertion statement in a separate function
2. Execute that function after a delay, using method below.

> performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:

UIViewController calls the callback method viewDidLoad: after loadView finishes its execution. It executes on main dispatch queue. So, it must be getting executed after your test function is over. (main queue is a serial queue where one task needs to be complete before starting next task)

This is avoided when performSelector: is used, and can solve the issue.